# Save my own topology:Mininet

Tags: python, mininet, sdn

I'm a newer in Mininet, I started my topology with CLI command: "sudo mn", after that, I'm adding some hosts and switches... but I want to save it for the next time.
How can I do it?
Example:
 http://i1360.photobucket.com/albums/r653/HKati/Capture%20drsquoeacutecran%202016-04-23%20agrave%2007.08.02_zpsxcmh4u6s.png

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use text whenever possible. If you post an image use the facility provided in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question correctly but you can define your topology within a script:

Example my_topology.py

```
from mininet.topo import Topo

class MyTopo( Topo ):

    def __init__( self ):

        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts and switches
        left_host = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        right_host = self.addHost( 'h2' )
        left_switch = self.addSwitch( 's0' )
        right_switch = self.addSwitch( 's2' )

        # Add links
        self.addLink( leftHost, left_switch, bw=10, delay='10ms', loss=0, max_queue_size=1000 )
        self.addLink( left_switch, right_switch, bw=10, delay='10ms', loss=0, max_queue_size=1000 )
        self.addLink( right_switch, rightHost, bw=10, delay='10ms', loss=0, max_queue_size=1000 )

topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

Then you can start it with

```
mn --custom my_topology.py --topo mytopo --link tc,bw=10,delay=10ms
```

Comment: That means is not possible to do it with CLI directly?

Comment: If you're asking for saving the already created topology, i.e. export, I don't know if such a command exists but if you're willing to get rid of python, you can create a bash script to list what you typed before to use within cli.

Comment: Thank you so much!